# Comment templates to be used when flagging for closure / deletion

Tags: discussion, comments

Since it is preferable to leave a comment when moderating the site and one often finds oneself commenting the same thing over and over again, I thought we could compile a list of comment templates to use as reference.

Below is a list of templates one can use when commenting on posts which are low quality (not an anwer / I'm having this problem too / welcoming and guiding new users / etc). The comments are grouped by common usage patterns.

It's a community wiki so feel free to edit, extend, and improve!

---

## Available Comments

- [Question Comments](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4445)
- [Answer Comments](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4452)

Comment: This is a great idea, especially as it will not only expedite the process, it's  explicit. Following your template, I'll see what I can come up with for Too Broad and Unclear .. no promises :D

Comment: Really nice idea if you are bored to tears and try to force to write something the 389th time.

Answer (score 8):

## Questions

### Subjective / Opinion-Based Question

#### Recommendations - Places to Visit

`Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. Unfortunately recommending places worth visiting is off topic on this site. Since we all have different personal preferences, what might be worth visiting for me might not be for you. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.`

#### Recommendations - Places to stay

`Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. Unfortunately recommending places in which to stay is off topic on this site. Since we all have different personal preferences, accommodation that might be cheap/functional/nice/well-placed for me might not be for you. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.`

#### Recommendations - Cheapest way to ___ / etc.

`Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. [We don't really do recommendations here on Travel.SE.](/help) Moreover, "cheap" is a matter of opinion since what is cheap for you might not be cheap for me. Hence why I am voting to close as opinion-based. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.`

#### Recommendations - Best ___ to do / see / etc

`Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. [We don't really do recommendations here on Travel.SE.](/help) Moreover, "best" is a subjective term: what might be best for you might not be best for me. Hence why I am voting to close as opinion-based. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.`

### Too Broad Question

`Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. Your question has too many possible answers which does not allow us to give you all valid options and it does not allow you to choose an outstanding answer. Please rewrite the question so that a precise and verifiable answer can be given.`

### Unclear Question

Add comment here.

### Spam / Non-Disclosure of Affiliation

`Please disclose your affiliation. Also note that, [if most of your posts on SE are about your website then you are probably here for the wrong reasons](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3148/advertising-thats-not-spam/3149#3149) and will be considered as a spammer.`

Comment: I'd recommend one answer per comment type, since that makes it easier to discuss individual comments.

Comment: Also, note that `[tour]` will link straight to the tour without needing to add the URL.

Comment: @DavidRicherby One answer per comment type, or split question and answers? I'll begin by splitting by Q and A to see how it looks.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of [what we do on Computer Science](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/627/9550).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Cool list.

Comment: To supplement @DavidRicherby's comment about formatting, there are other ways to get around without needing the URL. For example, `help` will lead to the help center.  You can type it in lower case and it will capitalize automatically if necessary. A list of shortcuts can be found on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) SE meta post.

Comment: @Sue You can use backticks to format quoted text, e.g., `\`...\``

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's cool, thanks!

Comment: _Recommendations - Places to Visit_ shows like this: Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. Unfortunately recommending places worth visiting is off topic on this site. Since we all have different personal preferences, what might be worth visiting for me might not be for you. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.

Comment: *Recommendations - Cheapest way to ___ / etc.* show like this: Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. [We don't really do recommendations here on Travel.SE.](/help) Moreover, "cheap" is a matter of opinion since what is cheap for you might not be cheap for me. Hence why I am voting to close as opinion-based. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.

Comment: *Recommendations - Best ___ to do / see / etc* shows like this: Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. [We don't really do recommendations here on Travel.SE.](/help) Moreover, "best" is a subjective term: what might be best for you might not be best for me. Hence why I am voting to close as opinion-based. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.

Comment: *Too Broad Question* shows like this: Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. Your question has too many possible answers which does not allow us to give you all valid options and it does not allow you to choose an outstanding answer. Please rewrite the question so that a precise and verifiable answer can be given.

Answer (score 1):

## Answers

### I'm Having this Problem Too

`Welcome to [travel.se]. This is not a discussion forum; please do not answer a question with another question. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how this site works. If you have a **new question**, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.`

Comment: Suggested Edit. I'm having this problem too / Did you got any solution - > Please don't post comments as another answer. (if noob, then add) when you earn 50 rep, you will have the privilege to comment anywhere

Comment: It may be worth using magic links such as `[tour]` that automatically generates the link: [tour]. You can find [more info in Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/209901).

Comment: @fedorqui Go ahead and edit the answers. They're wikis after all. :)

Comment: It shows like this: Welcome to [travel.se]. This is not a discussion forum; please do not answer a question with another question. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how this site works. If you have a **new question**, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.